# How does Metasploit's payload work with a remote target?

Tags: metasploit, shellcode, meterpreter

I have some simple questions. I often use Metasploit in my pentest engagements.
It works fine when I'm inside a local network. Okay, we know that, when the payload is injected properly, it will give us a shell or other type of access. But what about remote machines?
This question originated from the fact that we are setting the local IP address and local port to our payload. If the victim opens it, it must give us a shell from the remote machine. But it didn't work even if I tested it on my friend's laptop (I manually executed payload.exe. NOTE: These 2 laptops are in different networks).
I just waited inside the terminal, but nothing connected to me.
So, how to configure the payload to force a victim to connect to me even if the victim is in another network? Like RAT.

Comment: This might be the most asked question on different forums. If you Google it, you would find hundreds of articles how to traverse NAT-ed IPs in Metasploit payload. Take a look at https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2014/01/04/metasploit-meterpreter-and-nat/ for an example

Comment: @void_in thank you bro) I'm gonna test it. But if someone has broad explanation , please post here

Comment: You will get all the explanation in the article. There is no point in duplication. If you have questions after reading that article, post it here.

Comment: Have a look at [my question here](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/53534/8340). I usually go via the SSH tunnel route to a box on the cloud.